# react navigation + meteor + redux, navigationOption not respected or not applied

Tags: react-native, meteor, react-redux, react-navigation

i have question, here my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Meteor, {
  withTracker,
} from 'react-native-meteor'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class CreateCommunityContainer extends React.Component{

   static navigationOptions = {
       title: 'Community',
       headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                this.testFunction(par);
            }}>
                <View style={{marginRight:5}}>
                   <Text>NEXT</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>),
    };

    testFunction(par){
    ... some code
    }

    render(){
        ...some code
    }

}

const CreateCommunityMeteor = withTracker(({userId}) => {
   ...some code         
})(CreateCommunityContainer);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateCommunityMeteor);
```

my question is why navigationOption not respected or not applied, i expect that navigationOption give me the title "Community" in header bar but it is not. but if i put it in navigation router it work like usual, and how to make it take effect. btw i need to define navigationOption in screen class not in router, so i can call fucntion in that class from headerRight component of react navigation.

Comment: What do you mean "It's not working". How can help fix what we don't know is broken? Ask yourself a couple questions. What do I expect it to do? What is it actually doing? What have I tried already? I would recommend you recommend you take a look on [How To Ask A Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry to make you mad dude, i think its related to meteor, usually i dont use one. i just want to that static navigationOption to take effect, if i dont use use meteor package, navigationOption in screen class is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned that without the `withTracker` meteor function your component behaves as expected, I believe the problem lies with `withTracker` not taking the static property into the new component it creates.

You can try to set the `navigationOptions` property on the `CreateCommunityMeteor` component instead:

```
const CreateCommunityMeteor = ...

CreateCommunityMeteor.navigationOptions = {
    ...
};

export default connect(...)
```

I also noticed that you're calling `this` in your static function - this won't work, since a static function doesn't have access to the class instance.

In the same way, the static function I've suggested will not have access to it either.

To solve this, you can set `navigationOptions` to be a function: `({navigation}) => {...}` and pass what you need as a parameter to the route.